# JavaScript: V8 question: are small integers pooled?

Tags: javascript, v8

was looking at this [V8 design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11T2CRex9hXxoJwbYqVQ32yIPMh0uouUZLdyrtmMoL44/edit#) where it has a section for `Constant Pool Entries`

it says

> Constant pools are used to store heap objects and small integers that are referenced as constants in generated bytecode.
> and

> ... Small integers and the strong referenced oddball type’s have bytecodes to load them directly and do **not** go into the constant pool.

So I am confused: are small integers pooled or not?

My understanding is that it is not worth it pooling small integers if `sizeof(int) < sizeof(int *)` - because it is cheaper to just copy the actual integer instead of copying the pointer that points to the integer in the constant pool. Also variables that hold integers can be optimised to be stored directly in CPU registers and skip being allocated in memory first.

Also, are they located on the V8 heap or the stack? My understanding had always been that smis are just be the immediate values allocated on the stack instead of being a pointer + an integer allocated on heap. Also if you take a heap snapshot using chrome devtool you cannot find smis in the heap snapshot - only heap number such as big integers or double like 3.14 are on the heap until I saw this article https://v8.dev/blog/pointer-compression#value-tagging-in-v8

> JavaScript values in V8 are represented as objects and allocated on the V8 heap, no matter if they are objects, arrays, numbers or strings. This allows us to represent any value as a pointer to an object.

Now I am just baffled - are smis also allocated on the heap?

Comment: What I understand from this part of the text (I might be wrong) is that *constant* small integers are pooled. Variable small integers are not. TBH I have not read the complete document, just flew over the section you quoted. But this is the main difference I could spot on the fly.

Comment: I wonder what the differences are between constant small integers and variable small integers? Like `const a = 123` vs. `let a = 123`?

Comment: I think so. Also It says that "small integers that are referenced as constants in generated bytecode" so I think that small integer literals (eg. Those used in function calls, comparisons etc) also apply.

Comment: "*Also, are they located on the V8 heap or the stack?*" - I think you should ask that as a separate question. Afaik, everything is on the heap by default, and putting stuff on the stack instead is only an optimisation that may or may not be available.

Comment: @Bergi sure everything can be on the heap by default but to access data on the heap, you definitely need some pointer that is not stored on the heap. Normally that is done via pointers on stack. As far as I know, a program cannot directly access data on the heap.

Comment: @Joji No, all you need is an execution state which is managed by the instruction pointer and the call stack. Sure, the engine keeps pointer to lexical environments etc on the stack, but all the user data and references between the objects would be kept on the heap

Comment: sorry what do you mean by execution state and references between objects. by references did you mean pointers? can you give me an example? For example, if I have a script, and within it at the top level I have `const a = 'foo'; const b = {}` are variable `a` and `b` the pointers located on stack? I understand that string `foo` and `{}` are on heap that's for sure. but in order to access stuff on heap, you have to have a pointer **outside** of heap right. Or in what scenarios would the variable pointers i.e. `a` and `b` held in registers directly and skppped being allocated on stack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

V8 developer here.

> are small integers pooled or not?

They are not (at least not right now). That said, this is a small implementation detail and could be done either way: it would totally be possible to use the constant pool for Smis. I suppose the decision to build special machinery for Smis (instead of reusing the general-purpose constant pool) was made because things turned out to be more efficient that way.

> it is not worth it pooling small integers if `sizeof(int) < sizeof(int *)`

The details are different (a Smi is not an `int`, and constant pool slots are referenced by index rather than C++ pointer), but this reasoning does go in the right direction: avoiding indirections can save time and memory.

> are smis also allocated on the heap?

Yes, everything is allocated on the heap. The stack is only useful for temporary (and sufficiently small) things; that's largely unrelated to the type of thing.

The "trick" of Smis is that they're not stored as *separate* objects: when you have an object that refers to a Smi, such as `let foo = {smi: 42}`, then the value `42` can be smi-encoded and stored directly *inside* the "foo" object (whereas if the value was `42.5`, then the object would store a pointer to a separate "HeapNumber"). But since the object is on the heap, so is the Smi.

@DanielCruz

> What I understand [...] is that constant small integers are pooled. Variable small integers are not.

Nope. Any literal that occurs in source code is "constant". Whether you use `let` or `const` for your variables has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Did you just fix the design document? It no longer says "*Constant pools are used to store heap objects and small integers that are referenced as constants in generated bytecode.*" (as claimed by the OP) but only "*Constant pools are used to store heap objects that are referenced as constants in generated bytecode.*"

Comment: Yes. To avoid further confusion.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the clarification. I am still having a hard time understanding why smis have to be on heap - sure I understand that using pointer tagging (the trick you mentioned and is described in this v8 doc https://v8.dev/blog/pointer-compression#value-tagging-in-v8) we can just store `42` as part of the object on heap. That make senses. But what about smis not defined on an object e.g. `const a = 42; let b = 43` I think they are directly located on stack right since there is no need to introduce indirections - according to that v8 doc, I think smis `42` and `43` are on stack...

Comment: I think smis 42 and 43 are on stack along with other pointers that point to the heap. Also, I tried to use chrome devtool to take a heap snapshot for the case of `let foo = {smi: 42}` and `const a = 42;` I cannot find number `42` in the snapshot. If it is on the heap it should appear in the hepa snapshot right?

Comment: Yes, function-local variables are typically (not always!) stored as pointers on the stack. It's the same principle as object properties: usually these pointers point into the heap; for Smis the value is stored right in the pointer and there is no separate heap object for it. So yeah, you could say that _some_ Smis are _sometimes_ "stack-allocated", though I do think this statement is easy to misunderstand.

Comment: @jmrk since we are here, I would like to ask another related question regarding some v8 internals: is it correct to say that in V8, that every JS variable has its own block of memory and the address of that chunk of memory never changes during the lifetime of the variable? `let a = 5;` then later in the same function we do `a = 6` the memory location for `a` is not going to change right? only the content i.e. the bits that make up the value `5` changed to `6`? What about objects in heap, `let foo = {smi: 42}` later we have `foo = {smi: 43}` so what I think happened is that...

Comment: ... `{smi: 42}`  and `{smi: 43}` are different objects on heap for sure, so that reassignment is going to make `foo` points to the new object on heap, but variable `foo`'s own memory should only get rewritten for the new value (i.e. address of the new object) right? as opposed to switch to a new memory block?

Comment: No, that statement is too strong. For simple cases (function-local && non-captured && non-`with` && non-optimized && ...), variable reassignment works as you describe (a pointer in a known location is rewritten), but there are a number of cases where it gets more complicated (heap-allocated variables can move, global properties can move, optimized functions drop the whole concept of local variables, etc.).

Comment: Just curious about the statement "function-local variables are typically (not always!) stored as pointers on the stack". 1. what are function-local variables? I feel like pretty much all variables we have in JavaScript are function-local variables? because they are defined  inside of some function? 2. my mental model for stack vs. heap is that, in order to access things on heap, you have to use pointers allocated on stack (or static/global). I get it that most of the things in V8 are on heap but we have to use pointers on stack to access those on heap right? Or V8 does things just differently?

Comment: 1. There are global variables too. 2. Everything is accessed by pointer, and pointers can be stored anywhere. Yes there are many stack->heap pointers, but that's just a common case: there are lots of stack->stack and heap->heap pointers too, even heap->stack can happen. And when pointers are held in registers, they can point to heap or stack without the other memory region being involved at all.

Comment: if I have a script, and within it at the top level I have `const a = 'foo'; const b = {}` are variable `a` and `b` the pointers located on stack? I understand that string `foo` and `{}` are on heap that's for sure. but in order to access stuff on heap, you have to have a pointer **outside** of heap right. Or in what scenarios would the variable pointers i.e. `a` and `b` held in registers directly and skppped being allocated on stack?

Comment: With `const a`: might be on the stack, depends on what the rest of the script is doing. With `var a`, it's a property of the global object, which is stored on the heap. -- The optimizing compiler keeps everything in registers as long as it can; it'll spill to the stack only when needed (e.g. registers run out). -- This comment thread has gone on long enough now.

Comment: @jmrk thanks for the reply. But I found that `smi` doesn't seem to behave like what you said in this answer - if I have `let foo = {smi: 42}` and `let bar = {smi: 42}`, by using the memory profiling in Chrome devtool, I found that two `smi` are in the same memory location. I open up a new question, could you take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70819548/javascript-v8-question-are-small-integers-reused