# JavaScript: V8 question: are small integers reused?

Tags: javascript, v8

According to [this article](https://v8.dev/blog/pointer-compression#value-tagging-in-v8) from V8's blog and [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70734678/javascript-v8-question-are-small-integers-pooled), we know that small integers are encoded into the pointers directly with pointer tagging.

> The "trick" of Smis is that they're not stored as separate objects: when you have an object that refers to a Smi, such as let foo = {smi: 42}, then the value 42 can be smi-encoded and stored directly inside the "foo" object (whereas if the value was 42.5, then the object would store a pointer to a separate "HeapNumber"). But since the object is on the heap, so is the Smi.

This means that if I have two different objects with the same object values `{smi: 42}`. The smi `42` should be located in two different memory location on heap since the two objects are on heap and the value `42` is encoded directly into the pointer, instead of having an additional storage.

But this contradicts with the Chrome devtool's memory profiling result. Given this snippet

```html
<body>
    <button id='btn'>btn</button>
    <script>  
    const btn = document.querySelector('#btn')
    function MyObject() {
        this.number = 3.14
        this.smi = 123
        this.undefined = undefined
        this.true = true
        this.false = false
        this.null = null
        this.string = 'foo'
    }
    let obj1
    let obj2
    btn.onclick = () => { 
        obj1 = new MyObject()
        obj2 = new MyObject()
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

I thought `smi:123` should be located in two different locations while double `number = 3.14` should point to the same number object.

But this is not what happened - `smi` are in the same memory location and double are not.
[image]

Comment: not sure why smis are not in different memory locations @user2864740

Comment: See what happens with storing the value of `0x0fffffff` and `0x7fffffff` (the first comment did not have useful numbers). That should give some clues as to what “smi number” means, compared to “heap number”, in the Chrome develop tools.

Comment: From the link, the following is likely of relevance here “Note that a Smi value can only carry a 31-bit payload, including the sign bit. In the case of pointers, we have 30 bits that can be used as a heap object address payload [or we could use this to store a ~30 bit integer value instead].”

Comment: @user2864740 sorry not sure I understand what you are trying to say here. but yea I know the definition of `smi` and yes I have read the article linked by my own question.

Comment: I think I understand how pointer tagging works. As you pasted it here "a small integer [to be stored as part of the “pointer” value]." a smi can be encoded into a pointer. But `obj1.smi` and `obj2.smi` should be **different** pointers, so the integers should be stored in two different locations.

Comment: So to answer the question: no. Unlike CPython, small integers are *not* re-used. They just happen to be encoded directly in a way as “smi values” that avoids having to create an object to represent them.

Comment: can you maybe write up an answer instead of copy & pasting snippets from the article I linked in my own question?

Comment: As this does not apply to floating point numbers, it’s only logical that they would exist separately on the heap (unless a cache was used, which it is not).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An additional comment to @JonasWilms' great answer:

If you actually care about what happens under the hood, I suggest you learn how to use a (native, not DevTools) debugger and inspect the actual memory. DevTools are designed to help you understand what your app is doing, and while that has a lot of overlap with surfacing what's happening under the hood, it's not exactly the same thing, and there may well be certain details (like how Smis are presented) where this difference shows. I think heap snapshots use a `raw_address → object ID` map, and what you see is the natural result of putting Smis into such a map.

For a simplified version of your test case (just `function MyObject() { this.number = 12.5; this.smi = 23; }`), this is what you'd see in memory:

```
(gdb) x/5xw 0x1f010810aedc
0x1f010810aedc: 0x082c7db1  // pointer to map
                0x08002249  // pointer to properties (empty array)
                0x08002249  // pointer to elements (empty array)
                0x0810af71  // pointer to a HeapNumber
                0x0000002e  // Smi: 23 << 1 == 46 == 0x2e
(gdb) x/5xw 0x1f010810afa4
0x1f010810afa4: 0x082c7db1  // map (same as other object)
                0x08002249  // properties
                0x08002249  // elements
                0x0810afd9  // pointer to a HeapNumber
                0x0000002e  // Smi: 23 << 1
```

On another note, HeapNumbers can and do get reused. We don't see that in this example because of yet another mechanism: object properties use *mutable* HeapNumbers. Being mutable makes them unshareable, and in this toy example the whole approach just wastes time and memory; but it turns out to be a beneficial tradeoff for typical usage patterns, because it allows updating the value (in particular, from optimized code) without allocating a new HeapNumber every time.
If you simply had a `function f() { return 12.5; }`, it would actually return the same reused HeapNumber every time it's called.

Comment: Got it thanks so much! 1. is there a tutorial or doc on how to use the native debugger on V8? 2. is it correct to say that heap numbers that are pointed by object properties (like the example in my question) are always un-reusable mutable HeapNumbers? 3. This is a bit tangential, but is it correct to say that to the JavaScript variables, i.e. the pointers are either on stack or in registers directly, because in order to access the values on heap we have to use pointers outside of heap right? I understand pointers can be anywhere but ultimately they are either on stack or in registers?

Comment: @joji kind of, you always need to start from a known location in memory (e.g. the stack frame pointer, which resides in a certain register). The start does not necessarily have to be a register, it could also be a fixed location in memory.

Comment: 1. There's some stuff on v8.dev/docs, useful helpers in tools/gdbinit, and some `--allow-natives-syntax` functions like `%DebugPrint` and `%SystemBreak` are helpful as entry points. -- 2. No, only sometimes. -- 3. No (as you've asked before and I've replied before). The heap is full of pointers; even some variables are stored on the heap (when they're "context-allocated"); global properties are a common example of well-known heap memory locations being starting points for finding other pointers.

Comment: @jmrk thanks. I promise these are my questions: 1. "The heap is full of pointers" those pointers point to also data in heap right? but my understanding is that in order to access data on heap you have to use pointers **outside** of heap - I get it pointers can be also on heap but ultimate it needs to accessed by some other pointers, are those either on stack or in registers or fixed memory location? 2.  "global properties are a common example of well-known heap memory locations" does that mean it is a fixed location in memory?

Comment: @Joji 1. Yeah, sure. To access anything in memory (on stack or heap) you first need to load a pointer to it into a register. -- 2. No, not fixed. Global properties are referenced by the global object, which is elsewhere on the heap.

Answer (score 2):

> The smi 42 should be located in two different memory location on heap since the two objects are on heap and the value 42 is encoded directly into the pointer, instead of having an additional storage.

Yes. The SMI is stored twice, once inside each object values. So no, they're not reused, and actually can't be, as they're primitive values and not something referencable.

The dev tools do not show *where the pointer resides in memory* but rather *where it points to*, which in case of an SMI is a nonsense location as it actually encodes the value. Thus as both encode the same value, their "pointer to nothing" is the same.

Comment: +1. Since Smis don't point at anything, the whole concept of "reusing" doesn't really apply to them. Of course, two Smis storing the same value have the same bit pattern... but I wouldn't call that "reuse".

Comment: got it! that totally makes sense but I thought heap numbers are reused? like two properties with the value 3.14 should point to the same object on heap?

Comment: HeapNumbers _can_ be reused (e.g. when a value is copied around), but they're not globally canonicalized. If you have two computations, say one doing `3 + 0.14`, and another doing `314/100`, they'll each allocate a fresh HeapNumber for the result without checking if a HeapNumber for that value exists already -- such a check would be way too expensive to be worth it.

Comment: @JonasWilms can I ask more about fixed memory locations? I thought all memory locations would end up in registers since they need to be read/write?